# Gradle Pitest task works from cmd but fails in Jenkins

Tags: java, jenkins, gradle, jenkins-pipeline, pitest

I have a gradle script that goes along these lines (some parts were ommited).

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven { setUrl("https://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-prereleases") }
        maven { setUrl("https://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-addons") }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'info.solidsoft.gradle.pitest:gradle-pitest-plugin:1.7.4'
    }
}


plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version "$springBootVersion"
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version "1.0.14.RELEASE"
    id 'java'
    id 'com.vaadin' version "23.2.4"
    id 'jacoco'
    id 'info.solidsoft.pitest' version '1.7.4'
}

defaultTasks("clean", "build")

group = 'com.example'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '1.8'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { setUrl("https://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-prereleases") }
    maven { setUrl("https://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-addons") }
}

configurations {
    developmentOnly
    runtimeClasspath {
        extendsFrom developmentOnly
    }
}

dependencies {
    developmentOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools' //faster reloas
    implementation "com.vaadin:vaadin-core:$vaadinVersion"
    implementation "com.vaadin:vaadin:$vaadinVersion"
    implementation group: 'com.vaadin', name: 'vaadin-spring-boot-starter', version: "$vaadinVersion"
    //implementation "com.vaadin:vaadin-spring-boot-starter:$vaadinVersion"
    implementation 'org.vaadin.artur.exampledata:exampledata:3.4.0'
    implementation('com.vaadin:vaadin-spring-boot-starter')

    implementation 'com.h2database:h2:2.1.214'
    implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:$springBootVersion"
    implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation:$springBootVersion"
    implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security:$springBootVersion"
    implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools:$springBootVersion"
    implementation enforcedPlatform("com.vaadin:vaadin-bom:$vaadinVersion")

    testImplementation group: 'org.junit.jupiter', name: 'junit-jupiter', version: "$junitVersion"
    testImplementation group: 'org.junit.jupiter', name: 'junit-jupiter-api', version: "$junitVersion"
    testImplementation group: 'org.junit.jupiter', name: 'junit-jupiter-engine', version: "$junitVersion"
    testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test') {
        exclude group: 'org.junit.vintage', module: 'junit-vintage-engine'
        //implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security:$springBootVersion"
    }
    testImplementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:$springBootVersion"
    //testImplementation "io.github.bonigarcia:webdrivermanager:3.8.1"
}

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom "com.vaadin:vaadin-bom:$vaadinVersion"
    }
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
    include "**/**/*Test.class"
    finalizedBy jacocoTestReport
}

tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    options.deprecation = true
    options.encoding = 'UTF-8'
}

pitest {
    println("Running mutation tests...")
    junit5PluginVersion = '0.15'
    targetClasses = ['com.example.*']  //by default "${project.group}.*"
    pitestVersion = '1.7.4'
    threads = 4
    outputFormats = ['HTML']
    timestampedReports = false
}


configurations {
    developmentOnly
    runtimeClasspath {
        extendsFrom developmentOnly
    }
}
```

When I run gradle pitest from the cmd, I have no problem and the mutation tests are successfully executed.

When I run it from Jenkins, using the following Jenkinsfile, the task fails:

```
#!/usr/bin/env groovy

pipeline {
    agent any

        stage('Unit Tests') {
            steps {
                script {
                    if (isUnix()) {
                        //Linux Environment
                        sh './gradlew test'
                    }
                    else {
                        //Windows Environment
                        bat './gradlew test'
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        stage('Run mutation tests') {
            steps {
                script {
                    if (isUnix()) {
                        //Linux Environment
                        sh './gradlew pitest'
                    }
                    else {
                        //Windows Environment
                        bat './gradlew pitest'
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I cannot find anything related to the error and I cannot understand what the problem might be:

```
2022-11-01T22:58:48.439+0000 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle] Changing state to: FAILED
2022-11-01T22:58:48.439+0000 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle] Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.9\bin\java.exe'' finished with exit value -1 (state: FAILED)
```

My Java Version is "11.0.9".

What might be failing in order for this error to happen.

Comment: How does the task fail? Does pitest start or does the task fail before then? What error does it give? Do the unit tests run succesfully from your jenkins file? Are the jenkins nodes windows or unix?

Comment: The task fails with the error: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.9\bin\java.exe'' finished with exit value -1 (state: FAILED)

The unit tests are running successsfully and windows jenkins nodes are being used. 

I cannot understand the error message and I tried to run it in debug executing gradle pitest --debug and did not fin any usefull information. Do you have any ideas?